# ActiveMQ OpenWire C API problem

Tags: c, api, activemq-classic

I run ActiveMQ 5.5.0 broker on Ubuntu, downloaded and compiled APR 1.4.5 and C API related libactivmq and libopenwire.

The test c supplied in Examples at:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/sandbox/openwire-c/src/examples/

does not work, the issue is with the WireFormat magic code, see debug lines from the log:

2011-07-07 15:35:30,324 | DEBUG | Sending: WireFormatInfo { version=7, properties={CacheSize=1024, CacheEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, TightEncodingEnabled=true, StackTraceEnabled=true}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]} | org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator | ActiveMQ Task-2
2011-07-07 15:35:30,327 | DEBUG | Using min of local: WireFormatInfo { version=7, properties={CacheSize=1024, CacheEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, TightEncodingEnabled=true, StackTraceEnabled=true}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]} and remote: WireFormatInfo { version=1297154048, properties={}, magic=[^A,^@,A,c,t,i,v,e]} | org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:51606
2011-07-07 15:35:30,327 | DEBUG | Received WireFormat: WireFormatInfo { version=1297154048, properties={}, magic=[^A,^@,A,c,t,i,v,e]} | org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:51606
2011-07-07 15:35:30,333 | DEBUG | tcp:///127.0.0.1:51606 before negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=7, cacheEnabled=false, stackTraceEnabled=false, tightEncodingEnabled=false, sizePrefixDisabled=false} | org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:51606
2011-07-07 15:35:30,337 | DEBUG | Transport failed: java.io.IOException: Remote wire format magic is invalid | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///127.0.0.1:51606

I debugged the client side and captured values sent to the broker, 15 bytes, I will list them below:
1: '\001'
2: '\001'
3: '\000'
4: 'A'
5: 'c'
6: 't'
7: 'i'
8: 'v'
9: 'e'
10:'M'
11:'Q'
12:'\000'
13:'\000'
14:'\000'
15:'\002'
here last four bytes is version, which is set to 2

Somehow this message is shifted/misinterpreted by broker, so the magic token and version are wrong.

One more piece of information: I compiled libopenwire using both supplied versions ow_commands_v1.[ch] and ow_commands_v2.[ch], so I tried to link the test with both, the result is the same with either version. Does anyone know the reason for two versions? which one should I use?

Note: this message has been posted several days ago on apache forum, but no response. I hope on this site message will get more traffic.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenWire C API is not maintained by anyone so its not surprising that its broken.  There is a C wrapper for ActiveMQ-CPP in the ActiveMQ svn repo you could try using instead, if you are really married to using C.